# How to submit a form and then have the page refresh to that point on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out a way to submit a form on my site, the form will load the same page, that is action="", after the form has submitted how can I make the page load at the point of the form? Instead of the page loading at the top like it does by default?

Answer (score 1):

set an html anchor and use the anchor notation in the form action "mypage.html#myAnchor"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if it works after a form post, but maybe you can use an anchor in the action url? (http://www.scribblegraphics.com/articles/articles-anchors.html)